# How to use Environment Variable to set file from Java code?

Tags: java, environment-variables

I set environment variable CONFIG. Is it possible to use it to open file?

```
String path = "$CONFIG/app/users.json"
File file = new File(path);
```

PS

I cannot add whole path to file to the property file. It is required to use `$CONFIG` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `System` class's [getenv](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv(java.lang.String)) method like:

```
String path = System.getenv("CONFIG") + "/app/users.json"
```

So you could get whatever path you set in CONFIG variable and then you could append further path to it.

Answer (score 1):

There a built-in method, [`System.getenv()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv()) which returns a `Map` with all the environment variables, from which you can get the one you need:

```
Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
String config = env.get("CONFIG");
//and then
String path = config + "/app/users.json";
```